# Parameter "style" is undefined inside formatText function?

Tags: javascript, regex, recursion

> I am trying to make a text editor which formats text based upon following symbols:

1. `*` - **Bold**
2. `_` - *Italic*
3. `` ` `` - `Code`
4. `#` - Tag

> Very similar to the formatting you have seen here.
>
> *Basically, I want to make a text formatter similar to that in SO's post.*

```js
// REGULAR EXPRESSIONS
let boldRegExp = { re: /\*(?=.+\*)/g, markup: 'b', symbol: '*' },
 italicRegExp = { re: /\_(?=.+\_)/g, markup: 'i', symbol: '_' },
 codeRegExp = { re: /\`(?=.+\`)/gm, markup: 'c', symbol: '`' },
 tagRegExp = { re: /\#(?=.+\#)/g, markup: 't', symbol: '#' };

// ELEMENTS
let inputArea = document.querySelector('#input'),
 outputDiv = document.querySelector('#output'),
 resultText = undefined;

// RECURSION
let formatText = (text, style, index = text.search(style.re)) => {
 let str = text,
  strArr = str.split('');

 if(index >= 0 && str.lastIndexOf(style.symbol) !== index) {
  strArr.splice(str.search(style.re), 1, `<${ style.markup }>`);
  strArr[str.search(style.re)] = `</${ style.markup }>`;

  return formatText(strArr.join(''));
 } else {
  return text;
 }
};

// KEYUP EVENT HANDLER
inputArea.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
 resultText = formatText(inputArea.value, boldRegExp);
 resultText = formatText(inputArea.value, italicRegExp);
 resultText = formatText(inputArea.value, codeRegExp);
 resultText = formatText(inputArea.value, tagRegExp);
  
 outputDiv.innerText = resultText;
});
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
}
#input, #output {
 width: 44vw;
 margin: 3vw;
 padding: 7px 12px;
 border-radius: 6px;
}
#input {
 border: 0.5px solid black;
 font: 400 20pt consolas;
 outline: none;
}
#output {
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px 3px #EEE;
 font: 400 20pt Lato;
}
b {
 font-weight: 900;
}
i {
 font-style: italic;
}
c {
 font-family: monospace;
 background: gray;
}
t {
 background: #28F;
 border-radius: 2px;
 padding: 2px 4px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <textarea id='input' placeholder="Enter your question"></textarea>
 <div id='output'></div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src='./script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// REGULAR EXPRESSIONS
let boldRegExp = { re: /\*(?=.+\*)/g, markup: 'b', symbol: '*' },
    italicRegExp = { re: /\_(?=.+\_)/g, markup: 'i', symbol: '_' },
    codeRegExp = { re: /\`(?=.+\`)/gm, markup: 'c', symbol: '`' },
    tagRegExp = { re: /\#(?=.+\#)/g, markup: 't', symbol: '#' };

// ELEMENTS
let inputArea = document.querySelector('#input'),
    outputDiv = document.querySelector('#output'),
    resultText = undefined;

// RECURSION
let formatText = (text, style, index = text.search(style.re)) => {
    let str = text,
        strArr = text.split('');

    if(index >= 0 && str.lastIndexOf(style.symbol) !== index) {
        strArr.splice(str.search(style.re), 1, `<${ style.markup }>`);
        strArr[str.search(style.re)] = `</${ style.markup }>`;

        return formatText(strArr.join(''));
    } else {
        return text;
    }
};

// KEYUP EVENT HANDLER
inputArea.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    resultText = formatText(inputArea.value, boldRegExp);
    resultText = formatText(inputArea.value, italicRegExp);
    resultText = formatText(inputArea.value, codeRegExp);
    resultText = formatText(inputArea.value, tagRegExp);

    outputDiv.innerText = resultText;
});
```

## Problem

Everything works fine till I enter plain text. But, when I complete a markup, for example:

`*b*`

```
  ^ at this *. It gives the following error.
```

**Error**: Cannot read property `re` of `undefined` at:

**Error Line**: `let formatText = (text, style, index = text.search(style.re)) => {`

And, when I checked the debugger, it says that `style` is undefined.

[image]

> The `style` is defined till I write plain text, but when I **complete** a markup it raises error. Why is it so? And, how can I resolve it?

Comment: `style.re` so `style` is an Object literal, and `re` is it's property. Can you point out where's that defined in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the recursive call `return formatText(strArr.join(''));` you don't specify a style, therefore it's undefined; hence, it will throw the `style is undefined` error on `text.search(style.re)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend!